# Swift 4: value cannot be stored outside for-in loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, for-in-loop

```
    @IBAction func getListBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    var dict:Dictionary=[String:String]()
    var refData:DatabaseReference!

    refData = Database.database().reference().child("vacancies")
    refData.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            for vacancies in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let vacancyObject = vacancies.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let vacancyName = vacancyObject?["vacancyName"] as! String
                let vacancyNumber = vacancyObject?["vacancyNumber"] as! String
                list["\(vacancyName)"]=vacancyNumber
                //print("First List: \(dict)")
            }
        }
    })

    print("Second List: \(dict)")
}
```

I was trying to get the data from firebase and stored in a dictionary, but the values in dict can only be stored and printed in "First List", but not in "Second List" and printed "nil".

1) So how can I keep those values downloaded in firebase and print in "Second List".

2) how to stored the values in the dictionary and re-use them outside the func, eg. store the dictionary by UserDefaults?

Comment: "Swift 4: value cannot be stored outside for-in loop": Yes it can. It's just that you are missing the fact that `observe(value:with)` is asynchone. Look for "Async + Swift + Closure" to handle it.

Comment: Thanks Larme, I solved it with dispatch group.